# Why does a dynamically imported ESModule return JSON, when the module exports only plaintext?

Tags: javascript, typescript, heroku, es6-modules, deno

I am reasonably familiar with `ES2015 Modules`, but, right now, I am (simultaneously) getting my head around:

- `Heroku`
- `Deno`
- `Oak`
- `TypeScript`

I'm sure I've missed something elementary here, but I cannot find it.

I have two versions of a template, which look like this:

### `template-static.ts`

```
import page from './page.ts';

let template = page;  // Normally, the template will add a lot more to page

export default template;
```

### `template-dynamic.ts`

```
const page = await import('./page.ts');

let template = page;  // Normally, the template will add a lot more to page

export default template;
```

In this test setup, each template (whether using static or dynamic import) imports *the same module*:

### `page.ts`

```
let page = `

  <h1>Test Page</h1>
  <p>This is the <strong>Test Page</strong>.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Go to the <a href="/test-page-static-import/">Test Page (static import)</a> Page</li>
    <li>Go to the <a href="/test-page-dynamic-import/">Test Page (dynamic import)</a> Page</li>
  </ul>
`;

export default page;
```

Finally, I have the following **HTTP Server** (using `Oak`):

### `server.ts`

```
import { Application, Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';
import * as flags from 'https://deno.land/std/flags/mod.ts';

import templateStatic from './template-static.ts';
import templateDynamic from './template-dynamic.ts';

const {args} = Deno;
const DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;
const argPort = flags.parse(args).port;
const port = argPort ? Number(argPort) : DEFAULT_PORT;

const app = new Application();
const router = new Router();

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());


router.get('/test-page-static-import', ({ response }: { response: any }) => {
    response.status = 200;
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.body = templateStatic;
});


router.get('/test-page-dynamic-import', ({ response }: { response: any }) => {
    response.status = 200;
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.body = templateDynamic;
});

console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)

await app.listen({ port });
```

When I deploy the app to **Heroku** it works, but with the following outputs:

### /test-page-static-import

```
  <h1>Test Page</h1>
  <p>This is the <strong>Test Page</strong>.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Go to the <a href="/test-page-static-import/">Test Page (static import)</a> Page</li>
    <li>Go to the <a href="/test-page-dynamic-import/">Test Page (dynamic import)</a> Page</li>
  </ul>
```

### /test-page-dynamic-import

```
{"default":"\n\n  <h1>Test Page</h1>\n  <p>This is the <strong>Test Page</strong>.</p>\n  <ul>\n    <li>Go to the <a href=\"/test-page-static-import/\">Test Page (static import)</a> Page</li>\n    <li>Go to the <a href=\"/test-page-dynamic-import/\">Test Page (dynamic import)</a> Page</li>\n  </ul>\n"}
```

It's clear to me that the template which uses **static import** is importing `plaintext` and serving it as `text/html` while the template which uses **dynamic import** is importing `JSON` and serving it as `text/html`.

Why is the dynamic `import()` returning **JSON**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the return value of a dynamic import is not the default import as you are expecting it but an object wrapper around it.

Mind the example on the [dynamic import webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports).

```
return import('lodash')
    .then(({ default: _ }) => {
      const element = document.createElement('div');

      element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');
```

If you want to access the default import from a dynamically imported file, you have to access it via `resolvedPromise.default`.

In your case, you can access the default import from `page.ts` like follows:

```
const { default: page } = await import('./page.ts');

let template = page;

export default template;
```

Comment: Re: _"[..] the return value of a dynamic import is [...] an object"_ Brilliant, @Andre - that was the **single fundamental thing** I hadn't understood. Onwards and upwards. Thank you very much!